# Why does Akka Streams Balance not emit to the first available downstream consumer?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I expected that junction Balance would emits elements to available output ports. But if one of this ports is busy by some task then Balance will not emit any elements at all. Why does Balance emit this elements so slowly if it can emit them to available output ports?

This code i'm using. One of the flow do very long operation, another just only create simple object.:

```
  case class StartMills(mills: Long, flowName: String)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")

    val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val in = Source.repeat(System.currentTimeMillis())
      val out = Sink.foreach[StartMills] { start =>
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println((end - start.mills) / 1000 + s" sec. Flow: ${start.flowName}")
      }
      val merge = builder.add(Merge[StartMills](2))
      val balance = builder.add(Balance[Long](2))
      val slowFlow = Flow[Long].map { num =>
        scala.util.Random.shuffle((1 to 5000000).toList).sorted
        StartMills(num, "slow")
      }
      val fastFlow = Flow[Long].map(StartMills(_, "fast"))
      in ~> balance ~> slowFlow ~> merge ~> out
      balance ~> fastFlow ~> merge
      ClosedShape
    })
    g.run()

  }
```

This outputs:

```
8 sec. Flow: slow
8 sec. Flow: fast
13 sec. Flow: slow
13 sec. Flow: fast
17 sec. Flow: slow
17 sec. Flow: fast
22 sec. Flow: slow
22 sec. Flow: fast
25 sec. Flow: slow
25 sec. Flow: fast
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because all your graph will be run by a single actor which will effectively make your whole stream executed as if it was on one thread. Since you're simulating slowFlow by CPU intensive task (generate and sort a lot of numbers), whenever that flow executes, none of the other parts, including `Balance` can do anything else. This is by design.

To see the behavior you expect you need to explicitly add an **asynchronous boundary** in your stream topology. In your case you could do this:

```scala
val slowFlow = Flow[Long].async.map { num =>
      scala.util.Random.shuffle((1 to 5000000).toList).sorted
      StartMills(num, "slow")
    }
```

By doing so you would effectively make the slowFlow run in separate actor and `Balance` will be free to do its work while the slowFlow is busy. It's also now possible for slowFlow to asynchronously backpressure `Balance`.

You can read more on async boundaries in Akka Streams in the documentation here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#operator-fusion